# Why do AWS ec2 instances get degraded?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've been trying to get details on this but no luck. I've observed that if an ec2 instance has been running for many days (say 30-40 days), it gets degraded. Terminating that instance works.

But,

1. Why do ec2 instances get degraded? Is it because of the hardware or the software that we are running on it?
2. Is there anyway to avoid it?

Comment: What do you mean by "degraded"?

Comment: The instance health on AWS shows it as "Degraded" and the instance stops responding after that or works very slow.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a rare occurrence.

It means that there is an issue with the hardware on which the instance is running.

You can change the hardware by **Stopping the instance, and then Starting it again**. This will provision the instance on a different host computer.

If you have experienced this multiple times, then there is probably an issue with the operating system or application running on the instance. You should **contact AWS Support** for assistance.